# Closing Excel from within Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, delphi-xe2, ole

Would someone assist with what I'm sure is a basic error on my part please.

My goal is to open an Excel spreadsheet (invisibly), populate it, attach it to an email, send and close everything.

It is close to complete, except that Excel remains open - in the Task Manager - after the process is complete.

The block of code is:

```
procedure TFMain.SendEmail;
var
  i, j, r: Integer;
  vBody, vSaveVer: string;
  vAttach: TIdAttachment;
  vMftQty: array [1 .. 2] of Integer;
  vQtyTot: array [1 .. 12] of Integer;
  vNetTot: array [1 .. 12] of Real;
  oXL, oWB, oSheet: Variant;
begin
  IdMessage1.From.Address := 'sage@valid-email.co.uk';
  IdMessage1.From.Domain := 'valid-email.co.uk';
  IdMessage1.From.Text := 'Sage <sage@valid-email.co.uk>';
  IdMessage1.Subject := 'Sage';
  try
    SQLQuery1.Close;
    SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT comp,dept,e_addr FROM acc_email WHERE dept="' +
      EMailQuery.FieldByName('Dept').Text + '"');
    SQLQuery1.Open;
    while not SQLQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses :=
        EMailQuery.FieldByName('E_Addr').Text;
      SQLQuery2.Close;
      SQLQuery2.SQL.Clear;
      SQLQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE global_dept_number="' +
        EMailQuery.FieldByName('Dept').Text +
        '" ORDER BY account_ref, stock_code');
      SQLQuery2.Open;

      oXL := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
      oXL.DisplayAlerts := False;
      oWB := oXL.Workbooks.Add;
      while not SQLQuery2.Eof do
      begin
        oXL.Cells[r, 1].Value := 'Code';
        oXL.Cells[r, 2].Value := 'Description';
        oXL.Cells[r, j * 2 + 1].Value := 'Qty';
        oXL.Cells[r, j * 2 + 2].Value := 'Value';
        Inc(r);
        oWB.Worksheets.Add(After := oWB.Worksheets[oWB.Worksheets.Count]);
        oSheet := oWB.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Name := SQLQuery2.FieldByName('account_ref').Text;
        oXL.Cells[1, j * 2 + 1].Value := 'Month';
        r := 2;
        SQLQuery2.Next;
      end;
      if oWB.Worksheets.Count > 1 then
        oWB.Worksheets.Item['Sheet1'].Delete;
      oWB.Worksheets[1].Select;
      oWB.SaveAs(vSave + EMailQuery.FieldByName('Dept').Text + '.xlsx');
      SQLQuery1.Next;
    end;
    try
      if IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses <> '' then
      begin
        vAttach := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts,
          vSave + EMailQuery.FieldByName('Dept').Text + '.xlsx');
        IdSMTP1.Connect;
        IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
        IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := '';
        IdMessage1.Body.Text := '';
      end;
    finally
      if IdSMTP1.Connected then
        IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    vAttach.Free;
    oSheet := Unassigned;
    oWB := Unassigned;
    oXL.Quit;
    oXL := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

Yet Excel remains in the Task Manager and as the process runs a few times over the day, they build up in the background.

Could someone direct me to either the solution or how to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: in the part not shown, is there another global variable keeping a comobject which is not set to Unassigned ? E.g. `aSelect := oXL.Selection;`

Comment: It's frustrating when you withhold and conceal the code. Why can't you show a complete program that demonstrates the problem? It's trivially easy to do that. Why make it hard for us? An aside from what I can see. Your use of try/finally is wrong. The `try` always comes immediately after the resource is acquired.

Comment: I apologise. The entire code is now posted.

Comment: Thank you for that. However, now it's a giant wall of code and I can't imagine anyone wants to read it. Please try to find the middle ground and cut the code down to something digestible. An SSCCE. You might also take a moment to consider the wisdom of putting your entire program into a single procedure. I also find your use of try/finally disturbing, and the wanton abuse of `ProcessMessages` fills me with little hope. Sorry to be so morose.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your workbook isn't closed when you close Excel.  If your Workbooks are saved already then you can close them with Workbook.Close; Otherwise you can mark workbooks as saved before you close them (Workbook.Saved := True) or when you close them you can close them with:

Workbook.Close(False);

The false argument tells the Workbook to close without asking to save.  Once all Workbooks are closed then Excel should quit properly.